# Xamarin Android passing data from class to activity

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.ios

I made a Web API for my Xamarin Android app. And now I pass through the data from the Web API to android using JSON (JArray). And now I filled up a class with the JSON data, but I'm not sure how to get the data from the class into my android Activity.

Codes:
This is for requesting the JArray in my Web API to the Activity, and convert it to the class I made.

```
WebClient request = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://IPHERE/Database/api/Surfboards/GetSurfboards");
string surfboardsString = request.DownloadString(uri);
JArray theArray = JArray.Parse(surfboardsString);
Surfboard[] surfboard = (Surfboard[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(theArray.ToString());
```

This is my Surfboard.cs (Class)

```
class Surfboard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And eventually I have another question, I can upload an image that gets converted to a byte array for the JSON, but how can I turn it back into the image if the byte array is in the android app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all the variables in your class in public we can simply get those values from the object that the values you set by their name.

```
Surfboard sb= new Surfboard();
// set values of sb///

////
// get values of sb
string name=sb.Name;
```

Answer to your second question : You can turn byte array into image like following.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray .length);
```